# Magento 2: How to use the Layout Handle customer_logged_in?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, update-handle

Does Magento 2 have such handle as **customer_logged_in**? If yes how can I use it?

I tried to create

```
../view/frontend/layout/customer_logged_in.xml
```

and added there `<referenceBlock name="content" remove="true" />`

But content block wasn't removed. I renamed handle file to default and block was successfully removed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer to your question is definitely no, there is no `customer_logged_in` handle anymore, I've digged into the code and could not find any layout handle that could do the trick.

On top of that under `\dev\tests\static\testsuite\Magento\Test\Legacy\LayoutTest.php` you can find the following code:

```
/**
 * List of obsolete nodes
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_obsoleteNodes = [
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_simple',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_virtual',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable',
    'PRODUCT_TYPE_giftcard',
    'catalog_category_default',
    'catalog_category_layered',
    'catalog_category_layered_nochildren',
    'customer_logged_in',
    'customer_logged_out',
    'customer_logged_in_psc_handle',
    'customer_logged_out_psc_handle',
    'cms_page',
    'sku_failed_products_handle',
    'catalog_product_send',
    'reference',
];
```

Which to me, clearly tells us that the `customer_logged_in` layout handle is obsolete now.

See Fabian's answer for explanations about how it is done now in Magento 2.

Comment: those events are triggered when the customer **logs in** and when he **logs out**, not on every request.

Answer (score 9):

As others have pointed out, these handles are now gone. If you look at the Magento_Customer module, you'll see that blocks like the registration link are [always added](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml#L17-L21) but [not rendered if the customer is logged in](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Account/RegisterLink.php#L69-L73). It looks like this is now the preferred way to show elements conditionally depending on login state.

But this is not a solution for removing blocks based on their name, that were defined somewhere else. You could recreate the feature with an observer for `layout_load_before` that calls `$layout->addHandle('customer_logged_in')` if the customer is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sure I thought about adding handle that in my custom module. But it could look like spike and I wanted to use more native way. Thanks for explanation and example

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is still struggling with this I wrote a quick module that adds the customer_logged_in and customer_logged_out layout handles for you to use just like in Magento 1

http://frankclark.xyz/modules/magento-2-get-customer_logged_in-and-customer_logged_out-layout-handles

Enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

This is very stupid. I need to load block/template/resourse  only customer have permission, not just loggin or loggout. But i need to write 1000 lines of code to check if user have permission to see this. Just beautiful.