# Possible XML handles in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, update-handle

I'm aware of how the XML system in Magento works with handles such as `catalog_product_view.xml` and `catalog_category_view.xml` to define resources for specific (sorts) of pages.

For seperate simple products I need to have different XML files. It should be possible via [attribute sets](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/102) and I found this list of [obsolete handles](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106183/37536), but I can't find any list of what *would* work.

I've tried to add products to an attribute set (ID 9) and creating `catalog_product_view_attribute_set_id_9.xml` which loads a JS file with a `console.log` for testing purposes; no result.

Does anyone have any insight on which layout handles I could use to make differences between the same product type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Magento 2 introduces new layout handles.

First, there are the replacements for the M1 product types handles:

- `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml`
- `catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml`

Then, there is the layout handle based on the product id:

- `catalog_product_view_id_%productid%` where `%productid%` is the id of the product

And finally, there is a layout handle based on the product sku:

- `catalog_product_view_sku_%productsku%` where `%productsku%` is the sku of the product

As of 2.1.2, there is no layout handle based on the attribute set.

Comment: So the best option to have one XML for a set of products is to create a custom product type and use that for the handle? Seems excessive.. As I understand correctly I COULD use the XML based on ID or SKU, but I'll have to make a XML per product?

Also, can you explain why they'd make it based on `productid` AND `productsku` as they're both unique for each product?

Comment: @AlexTimmer Question 1: yes I reckon so. Question 2: unfortunately yes 1 XML per product. Question 3: I guess the purpose is to be able to modify layout for single products.

Comment: Raphael: Thanks for quick and clear answers!